# How to remove formulas and keep value in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to remove all the formulas in the cell of my table and to keep the values. I tried several methods but none of them worked.

```
Sub test()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau4").Range.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

This code always remove the header of my table.
I also tried this code :

```
Sub test()
For Each cell In ListObjects("Tableau4").Range
    cell.Value = cell.Value
Next cell
End Sub
```

It work, but it's way to long to execute.

Comment: Instead using `For Each Cell`. Just `Set RangeValues = YourTable.Range` and then `RangeValues.Value = RangeValues.Value`

Comment: `ListObjects("Tableau4").DataBodyRange.Value = ListObjects("Tableau4").DataBodyRange.Value`

Comment: Thanks, so it worked, but it's no longer a table

Comment: Thanks GSerg it's the solution I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the header row. You aren't allowed to have formulas in the header row. Concentrate on the DataBodyRange and use direct value transfer.

```
Sub test()
    with ListObjects("Tableau4").databodyRange
        .Value = .Value
    end with
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use:

```
Sub test()
With ListObjects("Tableau4").DataBodyRange
    .Value2 = .Value2
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe this will strip dates into integers.

Comment: @user11246173 Dates *are* numbers in Excel. This won't change the cell formatting so no dates will be displayed any differently.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Sub MAKE_VALUES()
Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau4").Range.Address) = Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau4").Range.Address).Value
End Sub
```

Note this will convert all table to values, including headers, and deleting format of table.

If you want to keep table format and convert to values only the body, excluding headers, then use:

```
Sub MAKE_BODY_VALUES()
Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau4").DataBodyRange.Address) = Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau4").DataBodyRange.Address).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: "`Range(Sheet.Range.Address)`" means "Create a Range on the active sheet that has the same boundaries as this given range from some particular sheet". If the given range belongs to the active sheet, the operation is pointless because it creates the same range, and you could just use the original `Sheet.Range`. If the given range belongs to a different sheet, then you just created a range on the wrong sheet without realising it.